# How do I disable low and critical battery notifications in 14.10?

Tags: 14.10, battery

The frequency of these warnings is too high and I don't need to be nagged into plugging in my laptop. How do I disable them entirely?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want to do this???

OK, go into a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'hibernate'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low 5
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 3
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-action 2
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy false
```

Obviously, set the percentages to something you like!

Comment: And as you're a reputation 23 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)

Comment: this works for Ubuntu 18.04 ,thank you